# How to eliminate the lock screen so the login form displays instead?

Tags: 18.04, login, lock-screen

I just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, and now I find that it's necessary to swipe up from the bottom of the lock screen just to get to the login form.  Is there some way I can eliminate this step so I just see the login form instead of the lock screen?  Why add an unnecessary step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just typing without the form being displayed?  For me (18.04.2 LTS), that causes GDM to display the login form.

Comment: Ha, yes, I just discovered that.  Problem solved.  Just gotta start typing the password.

Comment: I discovered it by accident myself. :)